# After changing Wordpress Permalink to "Post Name" then Page not found

Tags: php, html, wordpress, url, seo

I have wordpress site, after i changed the permalink to "Post name", then the sub pages (but home page is working fine) are not found "**Error occurred: 404 - not found**" . But if i changed to page ID - Plain url, then it is working but it show page ID in the url.

Pls check my screen shot of wordpress permalink http://prnt.sc/dfgba3

thanks

Comment: This is due to write permission issue. Please check the permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure your .htaccess file looks like this if you are using Apache.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Then try to clear your browser cache and visit the website. Or visit your website in incognito mode.

By the way if you are using Apache you need to enable mod rewrite in order to get perms links to work.

A command like the following if you are managing your own server

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply, can u show me how to do "enable mod rewrite in order to get perms links to work." and i changed the .htaccess file

Comment: do u have root access? please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Comment: hi actually my site is hosted, after hosted only the sub pages are not found

Comment: @P.S.F.Romesh I notice you have Yoast SEO plugin installed. Can you de-activate it before you try to change your permalink again?

Comment: if that doesn't work u need to write to ur web host, possibly rewrite mod is not on or something.

Comment: It may help somebody... I was struggling with the same problem, even after implementing the solution suggested. However, I just realized that I needed to set the "allowoverride" directive to "All" in my server apache config file.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure your .htaccess file on root is writable mode, means having 777 permission.

Can you please share .htaccess and share url of website

Comment: hi, Thanks for reply, I tried changing the .htaccess file permission but again it show the same issue